# laravel / angularjs JWT token refresh

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel-4, jwt

I am implementing JWT authentication in an angular/laravel application and I have a problem with token refresh.

Here the relevant code:

*PHP: the laravel-jwt listener that 'listen' for **tymon.jwt.expired** event:*

```
    /**
     * Fired when the token has expired
     * @param \Exception $e
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function expired($e)
    {
        $token = \JWTAuth::parseToken();

        Config::package('tymon/jwt-auth', 'jwt');
        $ttl = Config::get('jwt::refresh_ttl');

        $iat = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($token->getPayload()->get('iat'));
        $now = Carbon::now();

        // if renew ttl is expired too, return 401, otherwise let
        // the application generate a new token to frontend
        if ($iat->diffInMinutes($now) >= $ttl) {
            unset($iat, $now, $ttl);
            return response_failure(
                Lang::get('errors.api.auth.expired'),
                Config::get('status.error.unauthorized')
            );
        }

        unset($iat, $now, $ttl);
    }
```

*PHP: the 'after' filter:*

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| JWT-Auth token-refresh Filter
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The RefreshToken filter update the response headers by returning an 
| updated authentication token.
|
*/
Route::filter('RefreshToken', function($route, $request, $response)
{
    $token = JWTAuth::parseToken();

    try {
        $token->toUser();
    } catch (TokenExpiredException $e) {
        Config::package('tymon/jwt-auth', 'jwt');
        $ttl = Config::get('jwt::refresh_ttl');

        $iat = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromTimestamp($token->getPayload()->get('iat'));
        $now = \Carbon\Carbon::now();

        if ($iat->diffInMinutes($now) < $ttl) {
            $response->headers->set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' . $token->refresh());
        }
    }
});
```

*PHP: The authenticated routes filters:*

```
Route::group(['before' => 'jwt-auth', 'after' => 'RefreshToken'], function () { ... });
```

*JS: The interceptor that updates the localstorage*

```
'use strict';

angular.module('App')

    .factory('ResponseInterceptor', ['SessionService', 'jwtHelper', '$location', '$q',
        function (SessionService, jwtHelper, $location, $q) {

            return {
                response: response
            };

            // called for http codes up to 300
            function response(response) {
                var token = response.headers('Authorization');
                if ('undefined' !== typeof token && null !== token) {
                    SessionService.setToken(token.split(' ')[1]);
                }
                return response;
            }
        }]);
```

This works well except for one problem (workflow):

- token expires but is still able to be renewed
- angular send an http request with the expired token to server
- laravel catch the request and updates the response headers with a new token
- laravel blacklist the previous token

The problem is that if any request is sent from angular during the *"renewal"* delay, all thoses requests are refused from the server because the token is invalid (blacklisted).

Am I doing things wrong ? Can someone point me in the right direction ?

What I'd like to achieve is setting the ttl of the token at about 5 minutes, and allow the user to renew the token while navigating.

Comment: Same problem in Laravel 5.0.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am very interested in this solution as well

Comment: hey, this seems to be a known problem, check here, a fix should be available: https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/63#issuecomment-93138770

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a bug of the library, corrected now, [read here](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/63#issuecomment-93138770) for more informations

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using async requests? Then, you aren't sure if you're sending the most fresh token.

In this case you shouldn't use the refresh method after every request.

Comment: the problem was the one I commented, I'll put an answer so other people can find it easily

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. When a token is refreshed, last token will be blacklisted. 
however you need this token if another async call is started before last response. So a solution can be blacklisting last token with delay. And you can do this by setting `JWT_BLACKLIST_GRACE_PERIOD` in your `jwt.php` config file. ♥♥♥